# 22.04: How to add persistent routes in netplan

Tags: networking, server, iptables, netplan

What is the best way to add the following rules to netplan?

```
1 ip rule add from 172.16.9.132 table 128
2 ip route add table 128 default via 172.16.9.1
3 ip route add table 128 to 172.16.9.0/24 dev eth0
```

This would be my solution. I think that the first two rules are correct.
But what is the correct entry for the third rule?

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
      routing-policy:
        - from: 172.16.9.132
          table: 128
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 172.16.9.1
          table: 128
        - to: 172.16.9.0/24
          table: 128
  version: 2
```